# Apache Pig GROUP BY ,ORDER BY

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I have a bag containing tuples having playerName,gameName,score .
I first GROUP above bag BY game and put it in another bag.Now i want tuples with highest score for each game in another bag .How should i do this ?

Comment: Plz share the input data and expected output for the usecase

Comment: @MuraliRao Input file has tuples of this form : jon,mario,2345   joe,minesweeper,234   peter,mario,112      lisa,minesweeper ,900  I want highest scorers for each game ..mario ,jon ,2345  minesweeper,lisa,900.That is the ouput should have gameName ,playerName ,score for each game

Comment: you can use nested for each to achieve the same. have a look at the suggested answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input :**

```
jon,mario,2345
joe,minesweeper,234
peter,mario,112
lisa,minesweeper,900
```

**Pig Script :**

```
game_data = LOAD 'game_data.csv'  USING  PigStorage(',') AS (player:chararray, game:chararray,  score:long);
game_data_grp_by_game = GROUP game_data BY game;
game_kpis = FOREACH game_data_grp_by_game {
 ord_game_data_by_score = ORDER game_data BY score DESC;
 max_score_record = LIMIT ord_game_data_by_score 1;
 GENERATE group AS game, FLATTEN(max_score_record.player) AS player_name, FLATTEN(max_score_record.score) AS score; 
};
```

**Output : DUMP game_kpis :**

```
(mario,jon,2345)
(minesweeper,lisa,900)
```

Comment: why is FLATTEN used in this case ?

Comment: @MeetuAgarwal : max_score_record.player & max_score_record.score are bags we need to FLATTEN to get the record value. Try by removing FLATTEN from the above snippet, you will understand the need of FLATTEN.